# The Big O Notation and the Thetha Notation

Tags: asymptotics

I was instructed to find whether $$x*⌈x⌉*⌊x⌋$$ is$$ O(x^3) $$ or $$Big Thetha(x^3)$$
I tried to do a solution by cases, and i got :
if x is not an integer, $$x=b+є$$
$$⌈x⌉=b+1$$
$$⌊x⌋=b$$
Then $$x*⌈x⌉*⌊x⌋=(b+1)(b)(b+є)$$
If x is an integer , then $$x*⌈x⌉*⌊x⌋=x^3$$
How can i continue with my proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\lceil x \rceil < 2x$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$. So your entire expression is bounded above by $2x^3$.